# Handle "Share This App" from WebView

Tags: android, html, webview

I have an app with a `WebView` and HTML5. I want to add "Share This App" functionality.

Is it possible to do this directly from HTML5 / Java?

I can create a share intent, but I don't know how to connect with the `WebView`.

Comment: When you say "HTML5 / Java", do you really mean "HTML5 / JavaScript"?

Comment: Yes that it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to track your share url. just replace your url.equals("") and instead of startActivity you native code for sharing. this one works for whatsapp.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                                  @Override
                                  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                                      if (url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://")) {
                                          view.getContext().startActivity(
                                                  new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                                          return true;
                                      } else {
                                          return false;
                                      }
                                  }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCod,String description, String failingUrl) {
                                      Toast.makeText(activity, "Your Internet Connection May not be active Or " + description , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }
                              });
```